# Using HTML5 required on Javascript Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

i've a form with a submit button that after the click goes disabled for avoid double insert. Now i've a problem, with the jquery $("#element").submit() the browser doesn't process the required fields in the form. 
Here my code:

```
<form ...>
<input type='text' name='element' required/>
    <button onClick='disable_btn();' id='submitbtn' type="submit"
      class="btn btn-info btn-md col-md-3"> SAVE </button>
</form>

<script>
function disable_btn(nometag)   
{$("#submitbtn").html('Saving...');
$("#submitbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#submitbtn").closest("form").submit() }
</script>
```

it works fine with `<input type='submit'>`

How can i validate (not empty field check) the form?
thanks

Comment: why don't you use a submit button and the submit event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @Arun has suggested, the fail-safe way to intercept a form submission should be done through the `.submit()` event instead of the `.click` event of a submit button.

Also, some code revision:

1. Avoid inline JS. Bind event listeners instead.
2. Chain your JS methods
3. Use `.prop()` for boolean attributes instead of `.attr()`.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $("#submitbtn")
    .html('Saving...')
    .prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='text' name='element' required />
  <button id='submitbtn' type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md col-md-3">SAVE</button>
</form>
```